# array - keep only entries where key "alias" starts with an "a"

Tags: php, arrays

I just realized that i'm not accordingly familiar with the terminology of php-arrays. So I hope you people can get what I want to achieve.

I have an array like that, which holds several more "entries":

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 385
    [tag] => Aya Cissoko (Frankreich)
    [label] => Aya Cissoko (Frankreich)
    [alias] => aya-cissoko-(frankreich)
    [group] => 4
    [rank] => 266
    [group_id] => 4
    [group_name] => Künstler
    [group_alias] => kuenstler
    [group_field_type] => tagger-field-tags
    [group_allow_new] => 1
    [group_remove_unused] => 0
    [group_allow_blank] => 1
    [group_allow_type] => 1
    [group_show_autotag] => 0
    [group_hide_input] => 0
    [group_tag_limit] => 0
    [group_show_for_templates] => 3,36,44
    [group_place] => below-content
    [group_position] => 3
    [group_description] => Vor- und Nachname (Land) - Beispiel: "Eli Abeke (D)"
    [group_in_tvs_position] => 9999
    [group_as_radio] => 0
    [group_sort_field] => alias
    [group_sort_dir] => asc
    [group_show_for_contexts] => sa
    [cnt] => 1
)
Array ( 
    [id] => 59
    [tag] => Babangoni wawa Chisale (Malawi)
    [label] => Babangoni wawa Chisale (Malawi)
    [alias] => babangoni-wawa-chisale-(malawi)
    [group] => 4
    [rank] => 18
    [group_id] => 4
    [group_name] => Künstler
    [group_alias] => kuenstler
    [group_field_type] => tagger-field-tags
    [group_allow_new] => 1
    [group_remove_unused] => 0
    [group_allow_blank] => 1
    [group_allow_type] => 1
    [group_show_autotag] => 0
    [group_hide_input] => 0
    [group_tag_limit] => 0
    [group_show_for_templates] => 3,36,44
    [group_place] => below-content
    [group_position] => 3
    [group_description] => Vor- und Nachname (Land) - Beispiel: "Eli Abeke (D)"
    [group_in_tvs_position] => 9999
    [group_as_radio] => 0
    [group_sort_field] => alias
    [group_sort_dir] => asc
    [group_show_for_contexts] => sa
    [cnt] => 1
)
```

I want to keep all entries, where the "alias" starts with an "a" and get rid off the rest of the array, but keeping the "structure" of the array, since I need all the other keys and values associated to each "entry".

How can I get this done?

Comment: What is your expected output for the sample data you have provided?

Comment: Can you please format a bit your code? (and show us what you've tried)

Comment: @Nick - Thanks for your conment... but erm... just keeping the entries where the "alias"-key starts with an "a", so based on my two lines of example there should be only left the first line. Does this help?

Comment: @EMEm thanks for the clarification, that's what I expected but I always like to be certain.

Comment: @Qirel - thanks for editing my first post, gonna try to do it like this next time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the unwanted elements from your array by comparing the first letter of the `alias` entry to `a`:

```
$out = array_filter($array, function ($value) {
    return $value['alias'][0] == 'a';
});
```

If you want a case-insensitive comparison (so it also matches `A`), use [`strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
$out = array_filter($array, function ($value) {
    return strtolower($value['alias'][0]) == 'a';
});
print_r($out);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/caBUM)

Comment: `$out = array_filter($array, function ($value) use ($letter) {` for a more dynamic approach

Comment: @Nick - thanks a lot for your answer. By using your first code-example, i get lost of many of the other keys and values, i just get this back: `Array (           [alias] => aya-cissoko-(frankreich) [group_sort_field] => alias [group_sort_dir] => asc )`

Comment: @Cid - thanks for helping too!

Comment: @EMEm this will only delete values that have an alias element starting with `a`; can you share some sample data which shows the problem you are having?

Comment: @Nick - i was supposing all data will be kept, like in my first post: `Array ( [id] => 385
    [tag] => Aya Cissoko (Frankreich) [label] => Aya Cissoko (Frankreich) [alias] => aya-cissoko-(frankreich) [group] => 4 [rank] => 266 [group_id] => 4 [group_name] => Künstler [group_alias] => kuenstler [group_field_type] => tagger-field-tags [group_allow_new] => 1 [group_remove_unused] => 0 [group_allow_blank] => 1 [group_allow_type] => 1 [group_show_autotag] => 0 [group_hide_input] => 0 [group_tag_limit] => 0 [group_show_for_templates] => 3,36,44 [group_place] => below-content...`

Comment: @EMEm if you look at my demo, that is what is returned for the sample data in your question. Is your input array in a different format to what is in your question?

Comment: @Nick - hm, I don't get it. But no, the input array is structured like it's posted in my question. But this all is inside a huge php-script (MODX extra "Tagger"), which isn't made for filtering by first letter. So I'm trying to edit it for being able to do an A-Z listing, each letter separately.

Comment: Hmmm... without seeing the rest of the code it's going to be hard to figure out what's going wrong...

Comment: You might want to consider just sorting the array instead by that first letter and then iterating through the result, putting out a header whenever the first letter changes; or perhaps grouping the array into another dimension with the first letter as key.

Comment: Thanks again Nick... gonna try and see what I can achieve with your fist recommendation. The array is already sorted, need to find out how to output a header when the letter changes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Something like this? https://3v4l.org/Jv7n2

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was quite easy. I just had to check in the array "phs" for the "alias" like this:

```
    if ( $phs['alias'][0] == 'a' ) {
        $out[] = $tagger->getChunk($rowTpl, $phs);
    }
```

Now I only get outputted all the entries whose "alias" starts with the letter "a".

Thanks for everyone who tried to help!